# Average of bidimensional array's columns with array.map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-sheets

I have an array that looks like this:

```
var array = [ [1,3,9],
              [4,6,8],
              [3,7,5],
              [2,8,4] ];
```

I want to get the average number of each column, but for now I was just trying to sum them. This is my code:

```
var sum = function(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
};

var tests = array.map(function(v, i) {
  return sum(array.map(function(v) { return v[i]; }))
});

return tests;
```

The output turns the sum correctly, but it seems to be doing as many sums as there are rows (4 rows), instead of 3 corresponding to the columns. This is the output:

```
tests = [10, 24, 26, NULL]
```

Any idea why is this happening? How can I perform the calculation only for as many columns as there are instead of rows?

**EDIT:**

I'm using [Nenad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4620771/nenad-vracar)'s answer which gives the correct result. But I need to implement it on Google Sheets's Script Editor, which doesn't seem to understand the shortened functions with "=>". I replaced the shortened pieces for the longer version, but I'm not getting the same result.

```js
var array = [ [1,3,9],
              [4,6,8],
              [3,7,5],
              [2,8,4] ];

var sums = array.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
    e.forEach(function(a,j) { r[j] = (r[j] || 0) + a;
                             if (i == array.length-1) { r = r.map(function(el){ return el/array.length; }); }
                            });
    return r;
  }, [])
  
console.log(sums);
```

I don't see any difference between this and the shortened version, yet this one returns:

```
sums = [0.15625, 0.75, 1.34375];
```

Instead of:

```
sums = [2.5, 6, 6.5];
```

The sum is done correctly, but when I divide "el/array.length" or even "el/4", the result are these 3 weird numbers. I don't understand where are those coming from. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` and `forEach()` to return result.

```js
var array = [
  [1, 3, 9],
  [4, 6, 8],
  [3, 7, 5],
  [2, 8, 4]
];

var sums = array.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
  e.forEach((a, j) => r[j] = (r[j] || 0) + a)
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(sums)
```

To calculate avg for each column you can add `map()` on last iteration of array.

```js
var array = [
  [1, 3, 9],
  [4, 6, 8],
  [3, 7, 5],
  [2, 8, 4]
];

var sums = array.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
  e.forEach((a, j) => r[j] = (r[j] || 0) + a)
  if (i == array.length - 1) r = r.map(el => el / array.length);
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(sums)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nenad! This other version does work on Google's Script Editor. I messed up a great deal with some parenthesis -_- This whole .map/.reduce functions are very new to me. Thanks again, Nenad!

Answer (score 1):

To get the average of each column you'd first have to know the amount of columns. Then grab each column with `map()` and to sum everything with `reduce()`

Now we have the column, the sum and then just divide by column length.

```js
const arrayColumn = (a, n) => a.map(x => x[n]);
const arraySum    = (a) => a.reduce((b,c) => b + c);

var arr = [ 
 [1,3,9],
 [4,6,8],
 [3,7,5],
 [2,8,4] 
];

for(i=0; i<arr[0].length; i++){
  console.log(arraySum((col = arrayColumn(arr, i))) / col.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will convert the 2d array of rows into a 2d array of columns and then maps each inner array of columns to an average. There is a little bit of boilerplate to make the inner reduce immutable you could use lodash/fp or another library to clean this up.

```js
const array = [ 
  [1,3,9],
  [4,6,8],
  [3,7,5],
  [2,8,4] 
];

const averageColumns = array => array.reduce((acc, row) => {
  return row.reduce((accRow, col, index) => {
    const cols = accRow[index] || [];
    return [...accRow.slice(0, index), cols.concat(col), ...accRow.slice(index + 1)];

  }, acc);
}, []).map(avg);

const avg = array => array.reduce((acc, next) => acc + next, 0) / array.length;

console.log(averageColumns(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

`map()` + `reduce()` solution

```js
var array = [ [1,3,9], [4,6,8], [3,7,5], [2,8,4] ];


array.map(function(item, i, arr) {
 arr[i] = item.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / 2;
   console.log(arr[i])
});
```

I'm a little fix up your code 
you have mistake here `return sum(array.map(function(v) { return v[i]; }))`

```
var array = [ [1,3,9],
              [4,6,8],
              [3,7,5],
              [2,8,4] ];
function sum(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
};

var tests = array.map(function(v, i, arr) {
  return sum(arr[i])
});

tests;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose the array of arrays,
popular utility libraries (ramda for ex) have a transpose implementation,
but it's easy to implement your own:

```js
const trans = arr => arr[0].map((_,i) => arr.map(x => x[i]))

var array = [ 
 [1,3,9],
 [4,6,8],
 [3,7,5],
 [2,8,4] 
];
const res = trans(array)
console.log(res)


// to get the sum you can use reduce
console.log(res.map( x => x.reduce((a,b) => a + b )))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do as follows;

```js
var array = [ [1,3,9],
              [4,6,8],
              [3,7,5],
              [2,8,4] ];
   result = array.map(a => a.reduce((p,c,_,a) => p + c/a.length,0));
console.log(result);
```

As per the comments... Yes they are right, the right solution should be through a switch of the `.map()` and `.reduce()`;

```js
var array = [ [1,3,9],
              [4,6,8],
              [3,7,5],
              [2,8,4] ],
   result = array.reduce((p,c) => p.map((n,i) => n + c[i]/array.length), Array(array[0].length).fill(0));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The sum of a column is requested, not the sum of an index.