# Find the average of each index in 2+ arrays to return a new array of averages

Tags: javascript, arrays

For this problem, what is the most ideal solution in JavaScript to take a bunch of arrays all with the same number of indexes which all have integer values and then return one array with the average of each index from each array.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
var data = [[ 12, 14, 13, 10 ], [ 11, 13, 12, 2 ], [ 18, 12, 3, 4 ]];
```

to return one single array with all the averages calculated like so:

```
[13.6, 13, 9.3, 5.3 ];
```

Comment: You need to try something by yourself and then, if you'll have a problems, ask here with some code to fix

Comment: Please do your homework yourself, then come with specific issues. Have a look at Array.filter .map and .reduce

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41667034/average-of-bidimensional-arrays-columns-with-array-map/41667094#41667094

Comment: @fadfad , it is working for you ?

Answer (score 1):

```
data=data.map(arr=>arr.reduce((old,new)=>old+new,0)/arr.length);
```

I dont give an explanation, i give the OP the ability to find out alone + learn it that way...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `map` function in order to calculate `average` for every `item` from array.I'm using `reduce` function in order to calculate the `sum` for every `item`.

Here is solution:

```js
var data = [[ 12, 14, 13, 10 ], [ 11, 13, 12, 2 ], [ 18, 12, 3, 4 ]];
console.log(data.map(function(item){
      return item.reduce( ( prev, current ) => prev + current , 0 ) / item.length;
}));
```